# FluentAutomation and selenium 2.32.1.0

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-testing, fluentautomation

I recently installed FluentAutomation with selenium 2.32.1.0 from nuget. However, When I try to open a page using the I.Open("http://") method I get the following exception: `Could not load file or assembly  'WebDriver, Version=2.25.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1c2bd1631853048f'`

The FluentAutomation version in nuget says that it depends on Selenium.Support (≥ 2.25.1) which lead me to believe I could install 2.32.1.0.  Does this mean that the FluentAutomation nuget package was built with a hard dependency on Selenium.Support 2.25 and I have to roll back my selenium components?

Comment: Certainly looks like it. You could pull FluentAutomation and then add a reference to the later version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is the version of ChromeDriver.exe we package. The hard dependency is there. If you download the latest ChromeDriver.exe from Selenium and add it to your project (make sure it gets copied to the /bin directory), Fluent won't unpackage its own older copy and the mismatch problem should go away.

We are working on making this more transparent to the user and pulling latest into the project on setup, rather than packaging it into our DLLs.

(Author of FluentAutomation)