# FluentAutomation and Selenium 2.33.0.0

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, fluentautomation

I'm getting the following exception when I try to run a test with FluentAutomation

> A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileLoadException'
>   occurred in FluentAutomation.Core.dll
>
> Could not load file or assembly 'WebDriver, Version=2.25.1.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1c2bd1631853048f' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Here's the stack trace

> at FluentAutomation.SeleniumWebDriver.b__0(TinyIoCContainer
>   container)
>   at FluentAutomation.FluentTest.get_I()

I've got the latest version of selenium from nuget but seems like there's some kind of hardcoded required version from within the fluentautomation dll

[FluentAutomation](http://fluent.stirno.com/docs/) genuinely looks amazing so would be great to be able to use it in my project.

@stirno please help!

---

[FluentAutomation and selenium 2.32.1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16303529/fluentautomation-and-selenium-2-32-1-0) looks decidedly similar to my problem but I've downloaded the latest ChromeDriver from Nuget and I'm copying it into my bin directory as prescribed.

I've also tried downloading the latest from [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/list) and copying that in.  No joy

---

I'm also using spec flow so here's my setup in case it helps...

```
[Binding]
public class WebScenario : FluentAutomation.FluentTest
{
    private readonly IObjectContainer objectContainer;

    public WebScenario(IObjectContainer objectContainer)
    {
        this.objectContainer = objectContainer;

        FluentAutomation.Settings.ScreenshotPath = @"C:\Work\Temp";
        FluentAutomation.Settings.ScreenshotOnFailedExpect = false;
        FluentAutomation.Settings.ScreenshotOnFailedAction = false;
        FluentAutomation.Settings.DefaultWaitTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
        FluentAutomation.Settings.DefaultWaitUntilTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
        FluentAutomation.Settings.MinimizeAllWindowsOnTestStart = true;
    }

    [BeforeScenario("Web")]
    public void BeforeScenario()
    {
        FluentAutomation.SeleniumWebDriver.Bootstrap(FluentAutomation.SeleniumWebDriver.Browser.Firefox);

        objectContainer.RegisterInstanceAs<INativeActionSyntaxProvider>(I);
    }
}
```

The exception happens when `I` is accessed for the first time injecting it into the `PageNavigator` object

If you're interested you can download a really simple source example from [github](https://github.com/bapti/FluentAutomationWithSpecflow/)

---

So I got this working...  I downloaded the FluentAutomation source from GitHub and built the latest dlls and dropped them in.  Looks like this problem should be dealt with in the next release :D

Comment: I'm going to repro this locally and take a look in the morning. Looks a bit different than what I've seen before. New NuGet version should come this weekend as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the latest source from the [github repo](https://github.com/stirno/FluentAutomation) and dropping in the built dlls worked for me